# Javascript Tampermonkey and Captcha

Tags: javascript, captcha, tampermonkey

This is my first post so don't be too hard on me.

I've made a script for Tampermonkey to do some tasks on a specific website. However, sometimes the captcha code appears and stop my script. It's a simple captcha, not images. So I thought about making another script to click on captcha and then merge the two of them.

Here is what I made so far for captcha

```
(function() {
'use strict';
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementsByClassName("recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark")[0].click(); }, 1000)})();
```

It works fine on https://patrickhlauke.github.io/recaptcha/ , here I tested it but on my website, it doesn't work.

Someone told me something like

> "It works if you yourself interact with the site because then it
>   "activates" the box But if you do nothing and just let the script do
>   its thing, it doesn't/shouldn't work It's loaded on another document,
>   so it's inaccessible through the document object If it was that easy
>   to click the box, no one would use recaptcha - its existence is solely
>   based on being unclickable by simple JS scripts"

I didn't fully understand this. Is there any way I can make it work?